# Workflow incorporating Subversion, FTP, Editor

Tags: workflow

Currently I am working on a project that involves the following daily workflow:

1. Update local code and edit
2. commit to subversion repository
3. ftp to a testing server

I have been using Netbeans to handle all of this but frankly it, combined with the other stuff I am running, eats up all of my machine's resources frequently leaving it sluggish. By switching to a lighter text editor, a standalone ftp client and a standalone svn client I avoid the slowdowns and resource hogging but working becomes clunkier as I move between apps. Basically I really like Netbeans but until I can get a more powerful machine (Macbook Pro next week?) I am stuck.

What is your workflow? Any suggestions on how I can improve mine? Can I cut out FTP with Subversion in some way?

p.s. Subversion use is cast in stone so no git. Also, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: What type of coding do you do?  HTML?  Web? DB? C? Makes a difference as to a toolset I'd recommend...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, I use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) as my editor of choice.  Lots of language goodies for speeding development in whatever language you're doing via [Bundles](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles).  It has an SVN bundle, which lets you update/checkout/commit directly.  I use that for quick updates/checkouts.  On my test server, I have another SVN working directory.  I set up an [SVN Post Commit hook](http://www.grepmymind.com/2009/03/07/svn-pre-commit-post-commit-hooks/) to 1) automatically update the test server with the latest code, and then 2) send a [twitter message](http://code.google.com/p/twitvn/) to inform other developers of the change.

If I want to do more in depth work on the SVN repository (tags, commit logs, diffs) I tend to use the command line, or use a dedicated client like [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/).

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) is an IDE, which also includes syncing with version control, and FTP.

Comment: The sort of coding I do is (in this order) Javascript, PHP, HTML/CSS. I really don't like Eclipse. Like Netbeans, which I prefer to the various Eclipse based products and which also has version control, etc., it uses too many resources for my setup. The post commit hook bit looks interesting, though.

Comment: Ok, so if you're going to a Mac, then you might also look at Coda (http://www.panic.com/coda/) , which supports a nice workflow for code editing, version control, file transfer in a single window (no context switching).

Answer (score 1):

maybe install svn on the testing machine and do an update automatically every ten minutes or so. Or at a specific time.

Just an idea.

Sascha

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the programming editors (Vim, Emacs, etc) support subversion integration.

The only missing link is the FTP to test server. You can do this easily with a post-commit hook in subversion.

If you want to run some pre-commit tests as well, check out this script I had written some time back:
http://code.google.com/p/svn-pre-check/

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is still looking for svn ftp connection i would suggest [svn2ftp](http://svn2ftp.com/).